# How to print a mongodb cursor?

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript

```
#Database Testing Method.
            socket.on 'databaseTesting', ->
                db.collection 'documents', (err, collection) ->
                    console.log 'Printing documents...'
                    console.log cursor.item for cursor in collection.find() when cursor.hasNext isnt false 
                    console.log 'Documents printed.'
```

I am trying to print the contents of this collection to the console of a mongo database running on a nodejs localhost server. The first and last console.log displays fine, but not the cursor itself. And no errors are thrown. Any ideas? The above is CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MongoDB cursor is not an array so you should use something like this instead for the second to last line:

```
collection.find().each (err, item) -> console.log item if item
```